# event.preventDefault() not working in Android Ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a input field which will only take number as input so it's input type is number.
But the keyboard visible on Android device is having a "." button on keyboard, so I am trying to prevent that button. using below code

```
onKeyDown = function(event){
          console.log('KEY: ' + event.which);
          if (event.which == 250 || event.which == 229) {
                event.preventDefault();
          }
      };
```

229 is the ASCII code for the "." key of numbering keyboard in Android.
Please help me

Updated:
1) This should work on mobile device.
2) Input type is "number"
All solutions work on browser but not in mobile.

Thank You
Sandip Jadhav

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413145/restricting-characters-in-input-field-to-a-set-of-characters check this..this might help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you could try different approach

I suppose `$scope.input` its a `ngModel` that contains input value

```
onKeyDown = function(event){
      console.log('KEY: ' + event.which);
      if (event.which == 250 || event.which == 229) {
            $scope.input = $scope.input.substring(0, $scope.input.length - 1);
      }
  };
```

**Warning** it will work only if cursor at the end of the string

Also check this topic [Restricting Characters in Input Field to a Set of Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413145/restricting-characters-in-input-field-to-a-set-of-characters)

Answer (score 0):

its better to use `preventDefault` as inline

```
<input name="firstname" type="text" ng-model="contact.first_name" required="required" placeholder="first name" ng-keypress="($event.which==32 || $event.which==229)?$event.preventDefault():''">
```

it will check for both keys and prevent inserting it
impotent to note **it wont prevent from pasting** these codes.here i have added keycode 32 for testing purpose it prevent inserting spaceba,change it as your requirement 
for more see this pen http://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/YVxLxX?editors=1010